# Recursively applying methods to terminal objects and container objects in python

Tags: python

I've Elems and Containers of Elems. A Container is itself an Elem.
Corresponding methods can be applied both to Elems and Containers.
For this I'd have the following classes (pseudo python code):

```
class Elem:
    def meth1(self):
        ...

    def meth2(self):
        ...

    def meth3(self):
        ...

class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elems = ...

    def meth1(self):
        for e in self.elems:
            e.meth1()

    def meth2(self):
        for e in self.elems:
            e.meth2()

    def meth3(self):
        for e in self.elems:
            e.meth3()
```

Refactoring so as to avoid as much duplicated code as possible:

```
class Elem(object):
    # An Elem can be a terminal Elem or a composite Elem (Container)
    def __init__(self):
        self.elems = ...

    # specific meth1 code for Elem
    def meth1(self):
        ...
    def meth2(self):
        ...
    def meth3(self):
        ...

class Container(Elem):
    #apply meth to each contained Elem
    def each(self, meth):
        for e in self.elems:
            e.meth()

    def meth1(self):
        self.each(meth1)

    def meth2(self):
        self.each(meth2)

    def meth3(self):
        self.each(meth3)
```

How do I pass a polimorphic method (meth) as argument?
What's the best way to implement this idea?:

1.- functools.partialmethod? (only for python > 3)

```
def each(self, meth):
    for e in self.elems:
        e.meth()

meth1 = functools.partialmethod(each, meth = meth1)
```

2.- properties?

```
def each(self, meth):
    for e in self.elems:
        e.meth()

@property
def meth1(self):
    self.each(meth1)
```

3.- methods as strings and getattr?

```
def each(self, methname):
    for e in self.elems:
        getattr(e, methname)()

def meth1(self):
    self.each('meth1')
```

4.- other alternatives?

Hope you get the idea

Comment: Solution 3 would work, but personally I think there is nothing wrong with using a for-each loop in every method.

Comment: Agreed, but the idea was to program `each` as a sort of `map` but with a method as argument instead of a function